# Java - Cannot Find Symbol in getLegalMoves()

Tags: java, methods, tags, compiler-errors, symbols

I'm currently trying to code a `getLegalMoves()` method in my attempt to code the game Othello. Problem is, in the `getLegalMoves()` method it keeps saying it can't find the symbol even though I clearly defined it. 
Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList <Location> getLegalMoves(String curColor)
{
    ArrayList<Location> legalmoves = new ArrayList<Location>();
    int i = 0;
        ArrayList<Location> occupied = board.getOccupiedLocations();
        ArrayList<Location> playeroccupied = new ArrayList<Location>();
        ArrayList<Location> occupiedopposite = new ArrayList<Location>();
        int b = 0;
        while(b < occupied.size())
        {
            if(board.get(occupied.get(b)).equals(curColor) == false)
                occupiedopposite.add(occupied.get(b));
            else
                playeroccupied.add(occupied.get(b));
            b++;
        }       

        int a = 0;
        while(occupiedopposite.size() > i)
        {
            Location location = occupiedopposite.get(i);
            while(board.getEmptyAdjacentLocations(location).size() > a)
            {
                ArrayList<Location> empty = (board.getEmptyAdjacentLocations(location));
                Location emptyspot = empty.get(a);
                int c = 0;
                while(playeroccupied.size() > c)
                {
                    int direction = (empty).getDirectionTowards(playeroccupied.get(c)); //this is the problem line, it can't find playerOccupied.get(c), I think
                    int d = 0;
                    Location checking = emptyspot.getAdjacentLocation(direction);
                    while(board.isValid(checking) && d != -1)
                    {
                        if(d == 0 && checking.equals("W"))
                            d = -1;
                        else if(checking.equals(null) || checking.equals("B"))
                        {
                            d++;
                            checking = checking.getAdjacentLocation(direction);
                        }
                        else if(checking.equals("W") && d != 0)
                            legalmoves.add(emptyspot);
                    }
                    c++;    
                }
                a++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    return legalmoves;
}
```

Comment: And on which line are you getting that error?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Are you calling this from the ```main``` method?

Comment: Lets see the exception .

Comment: I don't know what is this - `(empty).getDirectionTowards(playeroccupied.get(c));` supposed to mean, but that is certainly not correct.

Comment: Line 65, I put a comment next to it, just scroll sideways a little bit.

Comment: What do you mean by not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty` is a List:

```
ArrayList<Location> empty
```

And lists don't have a `getDirectionTowards(...)` method:

```
int direction = (empty).getDirectionTowards(playeroccupied.get(c));
```

So it is normal that that code fails to compile (the way the parentheses are unnecessary). Maybe you meant to write:

```
int direction = emptyspot.getDirectionTowards(playeroccupied.get(c));
```

Comment: Hm, I just tried that but it stills give me the same error message. Thank you for catching that though.

Comment: @EthanB In what class is `getDirectionTowards(Location)` located? You can only call it on instances of that class.

Comment: What is the signature of the method?

Comment: Oh geez. It's public int getDirectionToward(Location target). I put the "s" by accident. That seems to have fixed it, thank you for making me see that!